# ExtJS Costum store representation

Tags: extjs, store

I wander if there is any ExtJS way that I can load store with data and after it is loaded I can create in master panel other my components (custom panel) to show that data in my specific way?

[image]

I want display data from store in panel with my custom components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. If you only need to display the data then [DataView](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View) is tailored for this task.
2. If your really need a component (ie, something that encapsulates user interaction and not just display), then you need to create this component and as your store loads create a component per record and add it to your master panel.

To copy the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View) example of dataview (option 1):

```
Ext.define('Image', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name:'src', type:'string' },
        { name:'caption', type:'string' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    id:'imagesStore',
    model: 'Image',
    data: [
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-drawing.png', caption:'Drawing & Charts' },
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-data.png', caption:'Advanced Data' },
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-html5.png', caption:'Overhauled Theme' },
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-perf.png', caption:'Performance Tuned' }
    ]
});

var imageTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="thumb-wrap">',
          '<img src="{src}" />',
          '<br/><span>{caption}</span>',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
);

Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('imagesStore'),
    tpl: imageTpl,
    itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
    emptyText: 'No images available',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Can you share some info how to make that?

Comment: I've included some code for option 1. Do you also need an example of option 2? Do you really need a component?

Comment: If you have code near you yo could post it but if not than don't bother. I think XTemplate would work for me